# NSPredicate escaping a backslash character

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

I have the following code:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like[c] %@", projectName];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
[moc executeFetchRequest:request error:error]; // moc & error are defined elsewhere
```

When I run this code with projectName being "asdf" everything works great. However, when the value is set to "asdf\" (note the backslash at the end), the following exception is presented:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The backslash is a wildcard char, and cannot appear unescaped at the end of a string.'
```

*po request* provides me with the following information:

```
po request
<NSFetchRequest: 0x101348ee0> (entity: Project; predicate: (name LIKE[c] "asdf\\"); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )
```

Seems to me this is a simple issue but cannot find a solution on the Internet, who knows one?

Comment: But "asdf/" has a forward slash at the end, not a backslash.

Comment: And do you really need "LIKE", which handles ? and * wildcards? Otherwise you could use "CONTAINS" instead.

Comment: Thanks Martin! It didn't had to handle ? and * wildcards so I changed the predicate to `name ==[c] %@` and now it works flawlessly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LIKE` in a predicate handles `*` and `?` as *wildcard characters*,
where `?` matches 1 character and `*` matches 0 or more characters. These wildcard
characters can be *escaped* as `\*` or `\?` to match a asterisk or question mark verbatim.

As a consequence, the backslash itself must be escaped as `\\` in a "LIKE" query 
to match a single backslash. A *single backslash* at the end of the search pattern
causes an error (that's what happened in your case).

If you don't need the wildcard handling, you can use `==`, `BEGINSWITH` or `CONTAINS` instead.
All of these can be combined with `[c]`.